# Why could a modest spark broadcast variable make a job hang?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

here's a code snippet. (problem description below)

```
val broadcastVarbannedDNS = sc.broadcast(filterList)
val INPUT = hc.table(s"tableName").where(s"DS BETWEEN 2016120100 AND 2016120100").rdd.filter(x =>  !broadcastVarbannedDNS.value.map(str => x.getString(2).contains(str)).contains(true))
INPUT.count()
```

filterList is a csv with 200k+ lines. Comes out to about 9MB.

When I run with the whole filter list, the job hangs at the filter stage and no exception or hint of what the problem is shows. Nothing on the logs either. However, when I cut the filterList file to a few hundred lines, it runs like a hot knife thru butter. Immediately, one could come to the conclusion that the "bigger" file is the issue, although 9MB is minute compared to something that should be able to handle GBs of cache. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine the issue is that if you have N records in the RDD and M lines in the filter then your processing is O(M*N) as you are checking each record against each line.

This means that if processing the N records is 1 second and you have 200K lines then you are running 200K seconds which would be the same as hanging.